# Python 3.6.2 Equality Comparison with Boolean Literal

Tags: python, python-3.x, equality, boolean-expression

As part of an assignment we've been asked to create a very basic/elementary program that asks for user input (whether they desire coffee or tea, the size, and whether they desire any flavourings), and then outputs the cost of the particular beverage, including their name and what they ordered, in addition to the cost. The code I wrote works perfectly; however, the only question I have is more for my own understanding. Our instructions for the customer's name were as follows: "The customer’s name – A string consisting of only upper and lower case letters; no
spaces (you may assume that only contains letters of the alphabet)."

Thus my code was as follows:

```
customerName = str(input('Please enter your name: '))
if customerName.isalpha() == False:
    print('%s is an invalid name, please try again!' % customerName)
else:
```

And then I just continue from there - however, PyCharm is telling me "expression can be simplified - this inspection detects equality comparison with a boolean literal" regarding the

```
if customerName.isalpha() == False:
```

statement. What would be the best way to simplify this?

Comment: `if not customerName.isalpha():` will do. don't compare to booleans.

Comment: if not customerName.isalpha():

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the result of `str.isalpha` directly; it's a boolean!:

```
if not customerName.isalpha():
    print('%s is an invalid name, please try again!' % customerName)
```